# Logging in the SalesForce with a PhoneGap APP with a Authenticated Website User

Tags: api, oauth2, authentication, phonegap

I developed a PhoneGap Connected APP that displays SalesForce logged user account details.
Accessing as Administrator can access the information I need.
accessing as a regular user (Authenticated Website license), the OAuth authentication displays incorrect login/password.
I accessed the regular user profile details and checked access to APP, but the user still unable to access.

Is there some setting I should do?
Can a Website Authenticated user access a Connected APP?

Observations:
I'm using JSForce library.
The user profile is a custom profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Authenticated Website User Licenses are only meant to be used with Force.com sites. You will not be able to use it with a connected app regardless of whether your hybrid app is built directly using PhoneGap/jsForce or you use the Mobile SDK.

You can read more about the authenticated website user licenses [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_platformportal.htm&language=en_US).